# Sql Compact randomly produces AccessViolationException

Tags: sql-server-ce, access-violation

I am running Sql Server Compact Edition 3.5.1.0 SP1 in a multi-thread application. The application randomly runs insert queries in transactions. With short transactions, it works fine. But when the transactions get longer and delay between executions get shorter or when I run the application in debug mode, SqlCE begins to throw the following exception randomly:

> AccessViolationException Attempted to
>   read or write protected memory. This
>   is often an indication that other
>   memory is corrupt.
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method,
>   ResultSetOptions options)    at
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at
>   SqlCompactTest.TransactedCommandGroupExecutionTest.Test()
>   in
>   D:\Projects\PlayGround\SqlCompactTest\SqlCompactTest\TransactedCommandGroupExecutionTest.cs:line
>   53    at
>   SqlCompactTest.ExecutionTest.RunTest()
>   in
>   D:\Projects\PlayGround\SqlCompactTest\SqlCompactTest\ExecutionTest.cs:line
>   60    at
>   SqlCompactTest.ExecutionTest.TimerElapsed(Object
>   sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) in
>   D:\Projects\PlayGround\SqlCompactTest\SqlCompactTest\ExecutionTest.cs:line
>   68    at
>   System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(Object
>   state)

The code I am running is:

```
IDbConnection connection = m_connectionProvider.GetConnection(); // Just returns new connection

connection.Open();
IDbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

foreach (IDbCommand command in m_commands)
{
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // This line throws exception
    Thread.Sleep((int)m_delayBetweenExecutions);
}

transaction.Commit();
connection.Close();
```

This code is running simultaneously in two threads. Connection string is:

```
"Data Source=testDB.sdf;Encrypt Database=True;Password=test;File Mode=Read Write;Persist Security Info=False;Max Database Size=1024"
```

I found absurd solutions on Internet like reverting back to Framework 1.1, changing the order of method arguments, enabling/disabling optimizations etc. but none of them worked for me. I also iterated through [possible solutions on microsoft sites](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=sql+server+compact+accessviolationexception+site:microsoft.com&meta=) but I could not find a solution that works for me. My database file version is 3.5.0.0.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because you set a connection to command.Connection does not mean it is set.

```
command.Connection = connection;
command.Connection.GetHashCode() == connection.GetHashCode(); // may return false.
```

This is the cause of the problem. Can be corrected by using connection.CreateCommand();

Answer (score 5):

[SQL CE objects are not thread-safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlservercompact/troubleshooting-access-violation-exception-while-using-sql-server-compact-database-with-ado-net-provider). Also, the same article lists a version mismatch situation (which happened in my case).

Comment: I had the same exception and it was exactly this, calling a backgroundworker that accessed my context while other processes were using it.